Why Microsoft Graph presence notification doesn't contain statusMessage?
I'm using this one:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changenotifications-for-presence
to subscribe to notification rich presence notifications. And all works fine but I don't get status message, which is part of the presence object, at least by the official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/presence?view=graph-rest-1.0
When I use get presence (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get the initial presence, I do get the status message.
Why is this inconsistent? Or am I missing something here when subscribing to presence?
